# Map HttpClient response data while returning an HttpResponse

Tags: rxjs, angular-httpclient

In my service I always convert the JSON to an actual class type using rxjs like so.

```js
get(id: UUID): Observable<OrderDTO> {
    return this.http.get<OrderDTO>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`)
        .pipe(
            map(x => OrderDTO.fromJson(x))
        );
}
```

I now have a case where I want to do that, but also get the HTTP headers as well.  So I'd add `{observe: 'response'}` to the `get` call and then return an `Observable<HttpResponse<OrderDTO>>`...except I can't figure out how to still do the appropriate `map` there.  Can someone help me with that syntax please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will get a returned HttpResponse Object from the http call, you can map your desire HttpResponse properties and response body and return an array for example

```
this.http.get<OrderDTO>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`)
        .pipe(
            map(resp => 
                [resp.headers,resp.body])
        ).subscribe(([header,body])=>....);
```